# How does Firebase Firestore consider document writes?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to explain my question with an example.
Example - I have a collection named "USERS" and there is one document named "ISURU".
The "ISURU" document has 3 fields named User_name, User_age, and User_gender.

1st Question- I'm going to set these fields with data at the same time like below:

```
db.collection("USERS").doc("ISURU").set({
User_name: "ISURU",
User_age: "22",
User_gender: "Male"

}).then(function(){console.log("Document successfully written!");)};
```

If I'm going to add data to Firestore like above, do they consider it as 3 writes or one document write, since they mention it is as document writes in [Understand Cloud Firestore billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#la)?

2nd question- Just imagine if I want to add above fields with data to Firestore using `{ merge: true }` like below:

```
function doA(){

var cityRef = db.collection('USERS').doc('ISURU');
cityRef.set({
User_name: "ISURU"
}, { merge: true });
}

function doB(){
var cityRef = db.collection('USERS').doc('ISURU');
ityRef.set({
User_age: "22"
}, { merge: true });
}

function doC(){
var cityRef = db.collection('USERS').doc('ISURU');
ityRef.set({
User_gender: "Male"
}, { merge: true });
}
```

If I'm going to run above functions at the same time does it count as 3 writes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. The first is counted as a single document write, irrespective of the number of fields and the second is counted a 3 different writes (it is a write every single time you call set/update/create)

BTW: I should point out that instead of calling `doc(...).set({...}, { merge: true })` with merge set to true, you can achieve the same partial update (add extra fields) simply by calling `doc(...).update({...})`

Comment: A difference between .set() and .update() is .set() will create the document if it doesn't already exist, and .update() will *FAIL*, so you need to check for/catch that possibility.

Comment: Yeah. That's true @LeadDreamer

Comment: @jayCodist Thank you very much for your explanation.